# Is there a way to make my laptop to startup much quicker?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, boot

Every time I turn my Dell Inspiron Laptop on, it takes a while for all of the things to load before I can use anything on my laptop. HELP !!!!

Comment: Are you willing to purchase hardware? Replacing your current hard drive with a solid-state drive (SSD) will give you a substantial improvement in how fast your system boots up.

Comment: optimize boot with xbootmgr: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140262

Comment: Resuming from suspend to disk (hibernate) will usually be much faster than booting and you can start working from where you left off which can save time opening various applications.

Answer (score 1):

Open the System Configuration Utility (Run -> msconfig or search in Start) and go to the Startup tab. Try disabling the programs which you think you don't need at startup.

You also open services (Run -> services.msc) and see if there are some services which you don't need to start automatically.